# Managed package in sfdx scratch org

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, scratch-org, dev-hub

How do I install managed package in scratch org? Probably, I need to make use of `sfdx force:package:install -i <package id> -k <installation key>`. But I do not want to purchase package again.

- installation key reusable across all of my scratch orgs? How does type of scratch org affect installation key usage?
- Also I would like to include managed packages dependencies as an external resource for my project so I can install them before pushing my source code, that might probably depend on packages, to scratch org.

Answer (score 2):

The installation key is the package password if any.

The scratch orgs are sandboxes so no need to purchase again as for the most part they are installed without licensing and don’t expire

The only issue would be if an ISV started auto suspending or expiring the user, user lead licenses which are what is created if you do not put a username when creating a scratch org.